# Stop Android Media Player loop that is started from a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-mediaplayer, android-lifecycle

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` that initiate a `MediaPlayer` and play a sound in loop. My Problem is, when the app is in the background and the receiver is triggered, the player plays the sound.
Now I want to stop the player, when I open my app again.  I tried to send a message to the receiver in `onResume` of an Activity but the instance of the player is null. How can I stop the player when I start / reopen my application?

Comment: can you add broadcastreceiver code.

Comment: solved it by implementing the player as a service. Ther service starts in the broadcast receiver and stops when the application comes in foreground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to control MediaPlayer from Service and use Context.startService() and Context.stopService() and handle MediaPlayer in his lifecycle

Use this Intent:

```
final Intent mpServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MPService.class);
```

When your BroadcastReceiver gets triggered use:

```
startService(mpServiceIntent);
```

When the Activity.onCreate() called use:

```
stopService(mpServiceIntent);
```